# Flash actionscript 3.0 help (Buttons)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript

I'm a flash beginner, and I would like to create a button that will play a few frames following the frame it's on (a fade out), and then travel to a different part of the timeline. Is there an easy way to accomplish this? Or would it be easier to program a fade with actionscript instead of with an alpha effect?

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help.

Comment: Yes, there is an easy way to do this. The functionality you're describing is what you would expect to learn from a brief tutorial for absolute beginners - have you found any resources that you're struggling with?

Comment: I just can't find somewhere that will tell me specifically how to do it. I know how to make a button play, and I know how to make it jump to a different part of the timeline, I just don't know how to make it do both of those things in order with one click. So for example, let's say the button is on frame 39. I want it to play frames 40-50, and then go back to frame 1 and stop, if that makes sense.

Comment: Simplest way is to make the button simply play from frame 40 and then on frame 50 put some code to go back to frame 1.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too, but the problem is that I have several buttons on the frame that all go to different places on the timeline. But I want them all the have the same fade out before going there. Thank you, though.

Comment: I see what you mean now, let me detail a possible way to go about it in an answer now :)

Comment: Also put your "frames" content in a MovieClip (same size as stage). This MClip becomes like a mini-stage itself which can go to different frames, so your button tells `MC_content_Holder.gotoAndPlay(40);` then add a "**stop**" command on frame 50 and followed by either a `MC_content_Holder.gotoAndStop(1);` or other code to fire a custom event at frame 50...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a frame with a few buttons on it and you want to have each button click through to playing a different frame but for all of those buttons to first perform some kind of fade out animation.

You can achieve this by storing a reference to the frame you want to go to after the fade out is complete. Something like:

```
var destinationFrame:int = 0;
```

And then when you click a button:

```
button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickButton);

function clickButton(event:MouseEvent):void {
    destinationFrame = 40;
    gotoAndPlay(<frame for fade out transition>);
}
```

Finally, at the end of the fade out transition:

```
gotoAndPlay(destinationFrame);
```

Simply allocate the relevant `destinationFrame` based on the button you click.